# Blank matlab code tooltips in Gnome 3, Debian Jessie

Tags: gnome, display

In the picture is shown what works and what doesn't work (also doesn't work for warning descriptions in the code).

Current version Gnome 3.14.1. I tried to change window style settings with gnome-tweak-tool, but it did not change the looks. What else could I try? It worked fine with Debian Wheezy, e.g. Gnome 3.4 (and probably some days ago, before installing the many every-day upgrades coming with Debian testing. -> I'm going to check the aptitude logs.)

[image: 3 different tooltip styles]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a well-known issue with Gnome >=3.10. Unfortunately there is no fix or workaround for it yet.

EDIT (link is broken) <s>Source: http://www.mathworks.in/matlabcentral/answers/125436-why-will-warning-error-messages-not-show-up-in-a-pop-up-window-when-i-hover-over-the-text-in-the-mat</s>

The only solution suggested by the answers on the Mathworks forum is to switch off Gnome and turn on some other desktop environment (Xfce, for example.)

Comment: well, the workaround to use xfce is helpful anyway. Together with the use different window managers in parallel, that solution would be enough.

Comment: The link is broken now; it would be nice if this answer could summarize the xfce workaround.

Comment: @tsbertalan it wasn't a workaround, they just suggested to use xfce or some other environment instead of gnome. Anyway, I edited the answer.

Comment: @AlessandroCosentino I see. I've been having this problem on on xfce myself, though. I actually answered a similar question on stackoverflow goo.gl/p0Szej -- the gist of it is that these broken tooltips only occur in the top 2/3 of my left monitor, for some bizarre reason.

Answer (score 1):

For tooltips related to code errors and warnings (orange and red squiggly underlines), you can generate a code analyzer report to see the messages.

In the Editor pane, click the down-arrow in the upper right corner and select "Show Code Analyzer Report". Note that the report will not run in parallel with code execution in the command window (so you can't see the report while you're waiting for your code to run).